# Considerations about derivable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a derivable function and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a so defined function: $g(t)=f(t+\cos (3t))$. We know that $f(1)=5, f'(1)=\pi$. Calculate $g(0)+g'(0)$ and justify.

I wrote $g(0)=f(0+\cos 0)=f(1)=5$ and $g'(t)=f'(t+\cos (3t)) \cdot (1-3\sin (3t))$ so that $g'(0)=\pi$. Is it right? Which considerations should I make?

Comment: `cos(1)` or `cos(0)`?

Comment: $\cos 0$, sorry

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: BTW I save typing with \to instead of \rightarrow. There is no \from. And \Bbb R is the same as \mathbb R.

Comment: And which considerations should I make? I think that it's what really counts.

Comment: I dk what you mean by considerations. It's perfect.

Comment: It says "give the adeguate motivations to the answer you give".

Comment: "Which considerations should I make?" You can say that you have used the chain rule.